# Add a Label to a ContextMenu MenuItem

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

Is it possible to add a label, or any node of sort to a MenuItem?
I want to be able to add a label that says **new** to MenuItems that reference new features,

Comment: Usually you use the `text` property for this purpose, but of course you could also set a `Label` as [`graphic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#graphicProperty). I combined with more conventional menu items this will probably look weird though...

Comment: The menuitems do have graphics already, i was wishing i can do it and be able to set its position to the far right [where the accelerator hint is placed].

Comment: Yes you can add any node to MenuItem ,but i guess you will have a problem with 'content display' position because this property does not available for MenuItem and that means the graphic still only on the left.